# Trying to write date cell with spout

Tags: php

this code writes a xlsx file using spot library

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    if(isset($result->id))
        unset ($result->id);
    $result = set_excel_type($result);
    $row = array_values((array)$result);
    $xls->addRow($row); 
}
```

and

```
function set_excel_type($element) {

        if (isset($element->encuestas_expiradas)) {
            $element->encuestas_expiradas = intval($element->encuestas_expiradas);
        }

        if (isset($element->encuestas_finalizadas)) {
            $element->encuestas_finalizadas = intval($element->encuestas_finalizadas);
        }

        if (isset($element->encuestas_validas)) {
            $element->encuestas_validas = intval($element->encuestas_validas);
        }
        if (isset($element->fecha_de_registro)) {
            $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $element->fecha_de_registro);
            $element->fecha_de_registro = $fecha->format('Y/m/d');
        }


        return $element;
    }
```

The problem its that date fields like $element->fecha_de_registro are written like strings on the xlsx file .It-s posible to wrtite then like a date cell?

Comment: Seems [Excel uses a a timestamp](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_dates_and_time.html) of a sort...

Comment: Using `$fecha->format('c');` the date can be sorted  but are still a string, and I need this format `d-m-Y` ,with this format a string date cannot be sorted correctly

Comment: I-m using `spout` not `xslxwriter`

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Spout XLSX writer does not support setting the type of data written in the cell. So if you pass it a string, it will use a "string" type for the cell, even though the string is in fact a formatted date.